# FQL and using its result

Tags: facebook, ios, facebook-fql

how can we use the result that we get from FQL

specifically
how can we use the result to save it in another array 
take in consideration that for iOS

Comment: any help?I am still hoping for an answer

Answer (score 0):

an example:

```
 NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid=4", @"query",
                                nil];
[facebook   requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query"
                         andParams: params
                     andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                       andDelegate: self];
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i am sure it will help other people.I figured out the answer to my Question which how to use the result of fql.query. All we have to do is to define array and save the result of the fql.query in this array to use it